# Specify a custom content type when publishing forms to a form library?

Tags: infopath, content-type

I'm on a project that use a lot of infopath form published in form libraries.
I'd like to create a query to retrieve all forms filled in a site collection (to create a global dashboard) but restricted to a specific set of forms (to be simple, only forms related to this project).

In order to achieve that, I was thinking on using content type inheritance :

- Form content type

  - My root form content type

    - Form 1
    - Form 2
    - etc.

When I publish the form from Infopath, I cannot specify the root content type.

What are my options ?

I also have a requirement that will probably make the problem a bit harder : the customer wants to be able to publish new forms himself (so asking him to do complex things is not possible). I have to create a form design template (with a header, etc.) so I can a bit of logic in the template if it can help.

thx for the help

Answer (score 0):

I have created several InfoPath forms that are published as content types in SharePoint.  All of these forms have a content type that is the same name as the form itself, and the parent type is either the same (in the actual document library for the form) or the standard SharePoint "Form" content type (when viewed from the site Content Types list).  But when you publish these types it lets you pick a "base" content type.  So I think what you want to accomplish is totally doable within the realm of InfoPath and SharePoint 2010.

Reference:  [Publish a form template to a [SharePoint] server running InfoPath Forms Services](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath-help/publish-a-form-template-to-a-server-running-infopath-forms-services-HP010100093.aspx#BM4)

Regards,

- Matt